# 1-player Battleship game - follow-up

Tags: python, game, python-3.x

**This question is a follow-up question of [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73603/simple-1-player-battleships-game).**

I've learnt a bit more Python since then. I recently came back to making [battleships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleships_(game)) again, and I think I did better.

These are the changes I've made:

1. Completely rewritten.
2. Multiple battleships.
3. Removed difficulty settings (as the way I was doing it before wouldn't apply to multiple battleships)
4. Separated UI and game logic

This is the code:

```
"""A simple in-interpreter game of battleships."""
__version__ = "2.0.5"

from random import randint
from math import sqrt


def getBoolFromInput(prompt, defaultReturn=None, yes=(), no=()):
    """Returns True / False / None from user input"""
    inp = "".join((char for char in input(prompt).lower() if char.isalpha()))
#   inp is now all the alphabetic characters in the input
    if inp in ("yes", "y", "yh", "definitely") or inp in yes:
        return True
    elif inp in ("no", "n", "nope") or inp in no:
        return False
    return defaultReturn


def getOrdinal(num):
    """Returns an ordinal string of the number that is passed.
 (e.g. 1 --> "1st", -32 --> "-32nd", etc."""
    negative = False
    if num < 0:
        num *= -1
        negative = True
    unit = num % 10
    if 4 <= num <= 20 or 4 <= unit <= 9 or unit == 0 or num == 0:
        suffix = "th"
    else:
        suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][num % 10 - 1]
    if negative:
        num *= -1
    return str(num) + suffix


def win(gameState):
    print("Well done! You won battleships! That was your",
          "{} time today.".format(getOrdinal(gameState.gamesWon)))
    print("You have played {} games so far, losing {}.".format(
        gameState.gamesPlayed, gameState.gamesLost * -1))
    return endText(gameState)


def lose(gameState):
    print("Oh no! You lost! That was your {} time today. Better luck".format(
        getOrdinal(gameState.gamesLost * -1)), "next time!")
    print("You have played {} games so far, winning {}.".format(
        gameState.gamesPlayed, gameState.gamesWon))
    return endText(gameState)


def endText(gameState):
    print("This give you {}% win and you have a {} game win streak.".format(
        gameState.gamesWon // gameState.gamesPlayed * 100,
        gameState.winStreak))
    while True:
        inp = getBoolFromInput("Would you like to play again? ",
                               None, ("again"), ("notagain"))
        if inp is None:
            print("Please type yes or no.")
            continue
        return inp


class Board:
    def __init__(self, height, length):
        self.height = height
        self.length = length
        self.items = []
        for i in range(height):
            self.items.append([])
            for i2 in range(length):
                self.items[i].append({"Current mark": "-",
                                      "Has battleship": False})

    def __repr__(self):
        """Returns the board with " " between every comlumn and "\\n"
 between every row."""
        return "\n".join([" ".join([self.items[h][l]["Current mark"] for h in
                                    range(self.height)]) for l in range(
                                        self.length)])

    def updateMark(self, x, y):
        if x > self.length or y > self.height or x < 1 or y < 1:
            return "OUT OF OCEAN"
        x -= 1
        y -= 1
#       -1 so a user's (1, 1) turns into an array index [0][0]
        if self.items[y][x]["Current mark"] != "-":
            return "ALREADY HIT"
        elif self.items[y][x]["Has battleship"]:
            self.items[y][x]["Current mark"] = "B"
            return "HIT"
        self.items[y][x]["Current mark"] = "X"
        return "NO HIT"

    def revealBoard(self):
        for y in range(self.height):
            for x in range(self.length):
                if self.items[y][x]["Has battleship"]:
                    self.items[y][x]["Current mark"] = "B"
                elif self.items[y][x]["Current mark"] == "-":
                    self.items[y][x]["Current mark"] = "O"


class GameState:
    def reset(self, turns, battleships):
        self.turnsTotal = turns
        self.turn = 0
        self.turnsRemaining = turns
        self.battleships = battleships
        self.battleshipsHit = 0
        self.battleshipsRemaining = battleships

    def __init__(self, disableConfirmations):
        self.disableConfirmations = disableConfirmations
        self.gamesPlayed = 0
        self.gamesWon = 0
        self.gamesLost = 0
        self.winStreak = 0

    def nextTurn(self):
        """Increments turn and checks if the game has ended"""
        self.turn += 1
        self.turnsRemaining -= 1
        if self.turnsRemaining == 0:
            return self.gameFinished(False)
        return True

    def hitBattleship(self):
        """Increments amount of battleships hit and checks if all have
 been hit"""
        self.battleshipsHit += 1
        self.battleshipsRemaining -= 1
        if self.battleshipsRemaining == 0:
            return self.gameFinished(True)
        return True

    def gameFinished(self, result):
        self.gamesPlayed += 1
        if result:
            if self.winStreak < 1:
                self.winStreak = 0
            self.winStreak += 1
            self.gamesWon += 1
            return win(self)
        else:
            if self.winStreak > -1:
                self.winStreak = 0
            self.winStreak -= 1
            self.gamesLost -= 1
            return lose(self)


class Battleship:
    def __init__(self, board, size):
        while True:
            east = True
            self.x = randint(0, board.length - size)
            self.y = randint(0, board.height - size)
            self.direction = randint(0, 1)
            valid = True
            if self.direction == randint(0, 1):
                self.direction = "EAST"
                x = self.x
                for i in range(size):
                    if board.items[self.y][x]["Has battleship"]:
                        valid = False
                    x += 1
            else:
                self.direction = "SOUTH"
                east = False
                y = self.y
                for i in range(size):
                    if board.items[y][self.x]["Has battleship"]:
                        valid = False
                    y += 1
            if valid:
                if east:
                    x = self.x
                    for i in range(size):
                        board.items[self.y][x]["Has battleship"] = True
                        x += 1
                else:
                    y = self.y
                    for i in range(size):
                        board.items[y][self.x]["Has battleship"] = True
                        y += 1
                break


def main():
    try:
        print(u"""Hello! Welcome to battleships, version 2.0.
Changelog:
- Complete rewrite
  - The game has multiple battleships now!
  - No longer any difficulty setting (because of said multiple battleships)
  - Now with \u221E% more classes!

Now, let's get started!
""")
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print("""Hello! Welcome to battleships, version 2.0.
Changelog:
- Complete rewrite
  - The game has multiple battleships now!
  - No longer any difficulty setting (because of said multiple battleships)
  - Now with infinity% more classes!

Now, let's get started!
""")
    gameState = GameState(getBoolFromInput("Would you like to disable " +
                                           "confirmation messages? ", False))
#   Main game loop
    while True:
        s = "tall"
        while True:
            inp = input("How {} would you like the board? ".format(s))
            try:
                inp = int(inp)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please type in a number!")
                continue
            if inp < 4:
                print("Please type a value greater than 3!")
            elif inp > 25:
                if not getBoolFromInput("Do you really want a board dimensio" +
                                        "n this big?", False):
                    continue
            if s == "tall":
                s = "long"
                height = inp
            else:
                length = inp
                if not gameState.disableConfirmations:
                    a = getBoolFromInput("Are you alright with a " +
                                         "{} by {} board? ".format(height,
                                                                   length))
                    if a is None:
                        print("I'll take that as a \"Yes\"")
                    elif a:
                        print("OK! Let's continue!")
                    else:
                        s = "tall"
                        print("Try again then.")
                        continue
                break
        board = Board(height, length)
        maxBattleships = int(0.5*sqrt(8*(height*length) + 1) - 0.5) - 2
#       Finds which triangle number the area of the board is inbetween
#       so you can't put more battleships than the board can take.
        while True:
            print("You can have a maximum of", maxBattleships, "battleships",
                  "with your board size.")
            inp = input("How many battleships would you like? ")
            try:
                inp = int(inp)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please type a number!")
                continue
            if inp < 1:
                print("Please enter a value greater than 0!")
                continue
            elif inp > maxBattleships:
                print("Please type a value less than", maxBattleships)
                continue
            if not gameState.disableConfirmations:
                a = getBoolFromInput("Are you alright with " + str(inp) +
                                     " battleships? ")
                if a is None:
                    print('I\'ll take that as a "Yes"')
                elif a:
                    print("OK! Let's continue!")
                else:
                    print("Try again then.")
                    continue
            break
        battleships = inp
        while True:
            inp = input("How many turns would you like? ")
            try:
                inp = int(inp)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please type a number!")
                continue
            if inp < 1:
                print("Please enter a value greater than 0!")
                continue
            if not gameState.disableConfirmations:
                a = getBoolFromInput("Are you alright with " + str(inp) +
                                     " turns? ")
                if a is None:
                    print("I'll take that as a \"Yes\"")
                elif a:
                    print("OK! Let's continue!")
                else:
                    print("Try again then.")
                    continue
            break
        gameState.reset(inp, (battleships * (battleships + 1)) // 2)
#                             This equation shows which triangle number
#                             the battleship represents
        allBattleships = {}
        for i in range(battleships, 1, -1):
            allBattleships[i] = Battleship(board, i)
#           This makes the battleships increase in size, with their
#           lengths like (1, 2, 3) or (1, 2, 3, 4) etc.
        playing = True
        while playing:
            if gameState.turn == 0:
                print("Let's play Battleships!\nTurn 1, {} turn{}".format(
                    gameState.turnsRemaining, "".join(
                        ["" if gameState.turnsRemaining == 1 else "s"
                         for i in (1,)])), "remaining.")
            elif gameState.turnsRemaining == 1:
                print("Last turn!")
            else:
                print("Turn {}, {} turns remaining.".format(
                    gameState.turn, gameState.turnsRemaining))
            print(board)
            s = "Y"
            while True:
                inp = input(s + " coordinate: ")
                try:
                    inp = int(inp)
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please type a valid number!")
                    continue
                if s == "Y":
                    s = "X"
                    x = inp
                    continue
                y = inp
                if not gameState.disableConfirmations:
                    inp = not getBoolFromInput("Are you sure that you want" +
                                               "to aim for {}, {}? ".format(
                                                   x, y), True)
                    if inp:
                        print("Try again then.")
                        s = "Y"
                        continue
                break
            aim = board.updateMark(x, y)
            if aim == "OUT OF OCEAN":
                print("That's not even in the ocean...")
            elif aim == "ALREADY HIT":
                print("You already hit that one.")
            elif aim == "NO HIT":
                print("You didn't hit anything...")
            else:
                print("Congratualtions, you hit part of a battleship!")
                cont = gameState.hitBattleship()
            if gameState.battleshipsRemaining != 0:
                cont = gameState.nextTurn()
            if gameState.turnsRemaining != 0 and \
               gameState.battleshipsRemaining != 0:
                continue
            else:
                board.revealBoard()
                print("\n" + str(board) + "\nThese were the battleships!")
            playing = False
            if cont:
                print("\n\nRestarting...\n\n")
                continuing = True
            else:
                continuing = False
        if continuing:
            continue
        print("Thanks for playing!")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I made it in a few hours (~3 to 4), so there are probably are some bugs; however, the game plays fine, and I can't find any bugs. I would like some feedback on 2 things:

1. if the classes are necessary for readability or just confusing
2. if my documentation using comments and docstrings is good enough.

Notes:

1. I am using camelCase over underscore_case as I prefer it, and find it more readable.
2. I am repeating many similar `while True:` loops as they are so very slightly different, that I couldn't get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imports should be ordered.

You mentioned

> I am using camelCase over underscore_case as I prefer it, and find it more readable.

but I'm still going to pick you up on it ;).

`get_bool_from_input` should really have a separation of concerns; the logic that needs abstraction is going from the input to the boolean. As such, you should probably have `bool_from_string` and let the caller call `input`.

In changing this, I noticed that you have

```
inp = not getBoolFromInput("Are you sure that you want" +
                           "to aim for {}, {}? ".format(
                               x, y), True)
```

Which joins to

```
"Are you sure that you wantto aim for {}, {}? "
```

This kind of error is hidden by the somewhat haphazard formatting. Going with the change to `bool_from_string`, I would use something like:

```
inp = not bool_from_string(
    input("Are you sure that you want to aim for {}, {}? ".format(x, y)),
    True
)
```

Even better, split the logic into several source lines:

```
question = "Are you sure that you want to aim for {}, {}? ".format(x, y)
answer = not bool_from_string(input(question), True)
```

...although immediately `not`ing the result and not giving it a meaningful name is a surefire way to confuse readers on what the code is actually trying to do.

Back to `bool_from_string`.

- I find the formatting a bit strange.

  - The comment is formatted oddly as it should be flush with the text.
  - There should be spacing after the doc comment.
  - Comprehensions inside function calls don't need brackets.
- The doc comment is wrong and largely unhelpful.
- `default_return` should just be `default`.
- `yes` and `no` should probably be `extra_yes` and `extra_no`. These should probably have precedence over the internal options.
- The internal options should be sets.
- The comment could be removed if you just named `inp` better.
- The sets should probably be globals.

```
YES_STRINGS = frozenset({"yes", "y", "yh", "definitely"})
NO_STRINGS = frozenset({"no", "n", "nope"})

def bool_from_string(string, default=None, extra_yes=frozenset(), extra_no=frozenset()):
    """
    Tries to decide whether the input means "yes" or "no".

    Returns True if the input means "yes", False if it means "no"
    and default if it's unknown. If extra_yes or extra_no are passed in,
    they must contain only lowercase alpha strings and will take
    precidence over internal checks.
    """

    alpha_lower = "".join(char for char in string if char.isalpha())

    if alpha_lower in extra_yes:
        return True

    if alpha_lower in extra_no:
        return False

    if alpha_lower in YES_STRINGS:
        return True

    elif alpha_lower in NO_STRINGS:
        return False

    return default
```

Personally, though, it's better just to do:

```
def bool_from_string(string, yes_strings=YES_STRINGS, no_string=NO_STRINGS, default=None):
    """
    Tries to decide whether the input means "yes" or "no".

    Returns True if the input means "yes", False if it means "no"
    and default if it's unknown. yes_strings and no_strings must
    must contain only lowercase alpha strings.
    """

    alpha_lower = "".join(char for char in string if char.isalpha())

    if alpha_lower in YES_STRINGS:
        return True

    elif alpha_lower in NO_STRINGS:
        return False

    return default
```

and callers can choose to call as `bool_from_string("foo", YES_STRINGS | {"foo"}, NO_STRINGS | {"bar"})`.

I would also make `default` a keyword-only argument:

```
def bool_from_string(string, yes_strings=YES_STRINGS, no_string=NO_STRINGS, *, default=None):
```

These changes also highlight this problem:

```
    inp = getBoolFromInput("Would you like to play again? ",
                           None, ("again"), ("notagain"))
```

Where `("again")` just means `"again"` and so the test `inp in yes` just checks that `inp` is a substring of `"again"`.

`getOrdinal` again has some strange formatting. Just fixing that and cleaning up the docstring gives:

```
def get_ordinal(num):
    """
    Returns an ordinal string of the number that is passed.

    get_ordinal(0)  = "0th"
    get_ordinal(1)  = "1st"
    get_ordinal(2)  = "2nd"
    get_ordinal(-32) = "-32nd"
    """

    negative = False
    if num < 0:
        num *= -1
        negative = True

    unit = num % 10
    if 4 <= num <= 20 or 4 <= unit <= 9 or unit == 0 or num == 0:
        suffix = "th"
    else:
        suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][num % 10 - 1]

    if negative:
        num *= -1

    return str(num) + suffix
```

The first block can be changed for:

```
negative = num < 0
num = abs(num)
```

Your check

```
unit = num % 10
if 4 <= num <= 20 or 4 <= unit <= 9 or unit == 0:
```

doesn't need the final `num == 0` as it implies `unit == 0`. However, it's easier just to invert the check:

```
if unit in {1, 2, 3} and num not in {11, 12, 13}:
    suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][num % 10 - 1]
else:
    suffix = "th"
```

This isn't enough, though, as `get_ordinal(111)` should return `111th` (it currently gives 111st). You should instead do

```
if unit in {1, 2, 3} and num % 100 not in {11, 12, 13}:
    suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][num % 10 - 1]
else:
    suffix = "th"
```

It's strange you modify `num` and then reverse the change; just use a different variable instead. Since the change is so simple, you can just stick with:

```
def get_ordinal(num):
    """
    Returns an ordinal string of the number that is passed.

    get_ordinal(0)  = "0th"
    get_ordinal(1)  = "1st"
    get_ordinal(2)  = "2nd"
    get_ordinal(-32) = "-32nd"
    """

    mag = abs(num)

    if mag % 10 in {1, 2, 3} and mag % 100 not in {11, 12, 13}:
        suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][mag % 10 - 1]
    else:
        suffix = "th"

    return str(num) + suffix
```

I would also suggest replacing

```
suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][mag % 10 - 1]
```

with

```
suffix = {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}[mag % 10]
```

In fact, you could even write:

```
# 11th, 12th, 13th
if mag % 100 in {11, 12, 13}:
    suffix = "th"
else:
    suffix = {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}.get(mag % 10, "th")
```

`win` is slightly misnamed; it only tells people that they have won and asks if they want to play again. This would be better named `alert_won_and_retry`. However, I would probably not conflate the two options and just have `alert_won`, leaving the caller to run `end_text`. It so happens that this would simplify code, too.

The formatting here is also haphazard. Line wrapping should be logical, not just whereever it fits.

```
print("Well done! You won battleships! That was your",
      "{} time today.".format(getOrdinal(gameState.gamesWon)))
print("You have played {} games so far, losing {}.".format(
    gameState.gamesPlayed, gameState.gamesLost * -1))
```

This also hides the same line-concatenation bug as before.

My personal style would use

```
print("Well done! You won battleships! That was your {} time today".format(
    get_ordinal(game_state.games_won)
))
print("You have played {} games so far, losing {}.".format(
    game_state.games_played,
    game_state.games_lost * -1
))
```

What matters isn't that your style is the same as mine or that it sticks strictly to line length guidelines but that it makes bugs *look wrong*. Whether this means you write things on loads of different lines:

```
number_wins_alert = "Well done! You won battleships! That was your {} time today"
number_wins_alert = number_wins_alert.format(get_ordinal(game_state.games_won))

print(number_wins_alert)

number_games_alert = "You have played {} games so far, losing {}."
number_games_alert = number_games_alert.format(game_state.games_played, game_state.games_lost * -1)

print(number_games_alert)
```

or do Lisp-style expression embebedding, the aim is to make the structure and logic coincide.

Exactly the same arguments apply to `lost`.

`end_text` is really misnamed; it should be something like `alert_finish_and_ask_replay`. This might suggest again that you split it up into `alert_finish` and `ask_replay`.

I have `alert_finish` doing:

```
def alert_finish(game_state):
    print("This give you {}% win and you have a {} game win streak.".format(
        game_state.games_won // game_state.games_played * 100,
        game_state.win_streak
    ))
```

This is buggy; `game_state.games_won // game_state.games_played` does integer division and then `* 100` will always give you 100 or 0. You should have done

```
int(game_state.games_won / game_state.games_played * 100)
```

or, better, just used the `{:.0%}` format specifier. The `.0` says there should be 0 fractional digits and the `%` displays the number as a percentage.

```
print("This give you {}% win and you have a {:.0%} game win streak.".format(
    game_state.games_won / game_state.games_played,
    game_state.win_streak
))
```

All of these `GameState`s are getting to me: it's a class so *of course* it's state. You should just call it `game`.

Looking at `Board.__init__`, we have the generation of a grid. This is simpler written as a comprehension:

```
cell = {"Current mark": "-", "Has battleship": False}
self.items = [[cell.copy() for _ in range(length)] for _ in range(height)]
```

I would be really tempted to change the grid cells to objects:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, current_mark="-", has_battleship=False):
        self.current_mark = current_mark
        self.has_battleship = has_battleship

class Board:
    def __init__(self, height, length):
        self.height = height
        self.length = length
        self.items = [[Cell() for _ in range(length)] for _ in range(height)]
```

`Board.__repr__`'s docstring should be reformatted again. Either like

```
"""Returns the board with " " between every column and "\\n" between every row."""
```

or like

```
"""
Returns the board with " " between every column and
"\\n" between every row.
"""
```

Further, the lines should be split up from their current squished self:

I would also use words to describe newlines.

Transposing can be done with `zip(*self.items)`, giving

```
def __repr__(self):
    """
    Returns the board with spaces between comlumns and rows on separate lines.
    """

    transposed = zip(*self.items)
    return "\n".join(" ".join(cell.current_mark for cell row) for row in transposed)
```

`updateMark` should really not be returning strings, but with this organization I don't see anything much easier than an enum.

```
class AttackSuccess(Enum):
    hit = 1
    miss = 2
    already_hit = 3
    out_of_bounds = 4
```

At point of use you should do

```
if aim = AttackSuccess.hit:
    print("Congratualtions, you hit part of a battleship!")
    cont = game.hit_battleship()

elif aim == AttackSuccess.miss:
    print("You didn't hit anything...")

elif aim == AttackSuccess.out_of_bounds:
    print("That's not even in the ocean...")

elif aim == AttackSuccess.already_hit:
    print("You already hit that one.")

else:
    raise NotImplementedError
```

which will trigger an error if the enum gets extended and the point of use isn't, not just break silently.

Again, the comment should be flush with the text.

```
if x > self.length or y > self.height or x < 1 or y < 1:
        return AttackSuccess.out_of_bounds
```

would be better as

```
if not (1 <= x <= self.length and 1 <= y <= self.height):
        return AttackSuccess.out_of_bounds
```

Personally, though, I would do `x -= 1; y -= 1` before calling the function: internal functions shouldn't be exposed to user-facing details like 1-based indexing.

No need for `elif` if you've already returned.

The name could be more descriptive; perhaps `attack_cell`

This gives:

```
def attack_cell(self, x, y):
    if not (0 <= x < self.length and 0 <= y < self.height):
        return AttackSuccess.out_of_bounds

    if self.items[y][x].current_mark != "-":
        return AttackSuccess.already_hit

    if self.items[y][x].has_battleship:
        self.items[y][x].current_mark = "B"
        return AttackSuccess.hit

    self.items[y][x].current_mark = "X"
    return AttackSuccess.miss
```

`revealBoard` is largely OK.

`GameState` should have its `__init__` function first. Its init function doesn't initialize all of its values; you have to then call `reset` to get that running. This suggests you have a bad separation of concerns; `Game` should be split into two classes where one handles the overall statistics and another handles the game itself. I would go with `GameStatistics` and `BattleshipsGame`.

With this, `gameFinished` should be split into three parts; `alert_finish` and and `finish_game` which are part of `GameStatistics`. The global `alert_finish` function can be merged into the local `alert_finish` method and the `alert_won` and `alert_lost` functions should become methods.

`ask_replay` would be called from the code that handles controlling the game (currently `main`) as neither class has any business dealing with it. `next_turn` and `hit_battleship` should return whether the game has ended *ignoring whether the user wants to replay*.

`turnsTotal` and `batteships` and aren't used, so remove them.

`GameStatistics.finish_game` would be

```
def finish_game(self, result):
    self.games_played += 1

    if result:
        if self.win_streak < 1:
            self.win_streak = 0

        self.win_streak += 1
        self.games_won += 1

    else:
        if self.win_streak > -1:
            self.win_streak = 0

        self.win_streak -= 1
        self.games_lost -= 1
```

You write `games_lost -= 1` but should really write `games_lost += 1`; you end up multiplying the result by `-1` whenever you use it anyway! You can also extract the zeroing logic:

```
def finish_game(self, result):
    self.games_played += 1

    if (self.win_streak > 0) != result:
        self.win_streak = 0

    if result:
        self.win_streak += 1
        self.games_won += 1
    else:
        self.win_streak -= 1
        self.games_lost += 1
```

It might be better to stick with the origingal logic for zeroing if this doesn't doesn't seem self explanatory enough, but it's the same deal as the old `cmp` function or Java's `compareTo`.

`disableConfirmations` would be better named as a positive; `confirmations_enabled`. It should also be removed from the `GameStatistics` class because it's neither used internally nor really benefits from encapsulation.

The `Battleship` class is a behemoth with only one method; `__init__`. This seems completely the wrong way to do it, especially because `__init__` shouldn't really be mutating things. If you want battleships to be made inside boards, add a method to the `board` class. In fact, you write:

```
allBattleships = {}
for i in range(battleships, 1, -1):
    allBattleships[i] = Battleship(board, i)
```

but never touch `allBattleships` again! This implied that a class is really the wrong abstraction in some sense; you're not using `Battleship` to store state but to stick itself onto the board somehow. Get rid of the class entirely.

In the constructor you use `self.direction` for two purposes. One is to hold a random boolean you use once and another is to hold an unused string. The first can be replaced with a `random.choice([True, False])` at point of use and the second can be removed entirely.

This can be further simplified by just writing `east = random.choice([True, False])` and not mutating it further.

Your loops can be replaced with ranges using the `start` and `stop` parameters.

This all gives:

```
def add_battleship(self, size):
    while True:
        east = random.choice([True, False])
        start_x = random.randint(0, self.length - size)
        start_y = random.randint(0, self.height - size)
        valid = True

        if east:
            for x in range(start_x, start_x+size):
                if self.items[start_y][x].has_battleship:
                    valid = False
        else:
            for y in range(start_y, start_y+size):
                if self.items[y][start_x].has_battleship:
                    valid = False

        if valid:
            break

    if east:
        for x in range(start_x, start_x+size):
            self.items[start_y][x].has_battleship = True
    else:
        for y in range(start_y, start_y+size):
            self.items[y][start_x].has_battleship = True
```

It makes sense to view these as rectangles to remove the two cases:

```
def add_battleship(self, size):
    while True:
        start_x = random.randint(0, self.length - size)
        start_y = random.randint(0, self.height - size)
        valid = True

        if random.choice([True, False]):
            width, height = size, 1
        else:
            width, height = 1, size

        for x in range(start_x, start_x+width):
            for y in range(start_y, start_y+height):
                if self.items[y][x].has_battleship:
                    valid = False

        if valid:
            break

    for x in range(start_x, start_x+width):
        for y in range(start_y, start_y+height):
            self.items[y][x].has_battleship = True
```

You could also use `all` here:

```
def add_battleship(self, size):
    while True:
        start_x = random.randint(0, self.length - size)
        start_y = random.randint(0, self.height - size)

        if random.choice([True, False]):
            width, height = size, 1
        else:
            width, height = 1, size

        xs = range(start_x, start_x+width)
        ys = range(start_y, start_y+height)

        if not any(self.items[y][x].has_battleship for x in xs for y in ys):
            break

    for x in xs:
        for y in ys:
            self.items[y][x].has_battleship = True
```

`main` is the real beast here, but I'm going to wait before tackling that.

I will post the updated code in another answer because I have run out of characters to add it to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code from the other answer.

```
"""A simple in-interpreter game of battleships."""
__version__ = "2.0.5"

import random

from enum import Enum
from math import sqrt

YES_STRINGS = frozenset({'definitely', 'y', 'yes', 'yh'})
NO_STRINGS = frozenset({'n', 'no', 'nope'})

def bool_from_string(string, yes_strings=YES_STRINGS, no_string=NO_STRINGS, *, default=None):
    """
    Tries to decide whether the input means "yes" or "no".

    Returns True if the input means "yes", False if it means "no"
    and default if it's unknown. yes_strings and no_strings must
    must contain only lowercase alpha strings.
    """

    alpha_lower = "".join(char for char in string if char.isalpha())

    if alpha_lower in YES_STRINGS:
        return True

    elif alpha_lower in NO_STRINGS:
        return False

    return default

def get_ordinal(num):
    """
    Returns an ordinal string of the number that is passed.

    get_ordinal(0)  = "0th"
    get_ordinal(1)  = "1st"
    get_ordinal(2)  = "2nd"
    get_ordinal(-32) = "-32nd"
    """

    mag = abs(num)

    # 11th, 12th, 13th
    if mag % 100 in {11, 12, 13}:
        suffix = "th"
    else:
        suffix = {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}.get(mag % 10, "th")

    return str(num) + suffix


def ask_replay(game):
    while True:
        inp = bool_from_string(
            input("Would you like to play again? "),
            YES_STRINGS | {"again"},
            NO_STRINGS | {"notagain"},
            default=None
        )

        if inp is None:
            print("Please type yes or no.")
            continue

        return inp

class Cell:
    def __init__(self, current_mark="-", has_battleship=False):
        self.current_mark = current_mark
        self.has_battleship = has_battleship

class AttackSuccess(Enum):
    hit = 1
    miss = 2
    already_hit = 3
    out_of_bounds = 4

class Board:
    def __init__(self, height, length):
        self.height = height
        self.length = length
        self.items = [[Cell() for _ in range(length)] for _ in range(height)]

    def __repr__(self):
        """
        Returns the board with spaces between comlumns and rows on separate lines.
        """

        transposed = zip(*self.items)
        return "\n".join(" ".join(cell.current_mark for cell in row) for row in transposed)

    def attack_cell(self, x, y):
        if not (0 <= x < self.length and 0 <= y < self.height):
            return AttackSuccess.out_of_bounds

        if self.items[y][x].current_mark != "-":
            return AttackSuccess.already_hit

        if self.items[y][x].has_battleship:
            self.items[y][x].current_mark = "B"
            return AttackSuccess.hit

        self.items[y][x].current_mark = "X"
        return AttackSuccess.miss

    def reveal_board(self):
        for y in range(self.height):
            for x in range(self.length):
                if self.items[y][x].has_battleship:
                    self.items[y][x].current_mark = "B"

                elif self.items[y][x].current_mark == "-":
                    self.items[y][x].current_mark = "O"

    def add_battleship(self, size):
        while True:
            start_x = random.randint(0, self.length - size)
            start_y = random.randint(0, self.height - size)

            if random.choice([True, False]):
                width, height = size, 1
            else:
                width, height = 1, size

            xs = range(start_x, start_x+width)
            ys = range(start_y, start_y+height)

            if not any(self.items[y][x].has_battleship for x in xs for y in ys):
                break

        for x in xs:
            for y in ys:
                self.items[y][x].has_battleship = True

class GameStatistics:
    def __init__(self):
        self.games_played = 0
        self.games_won = 0
        self.games_lost = 0
        self.win_streak = 0

    def alert_won(self):
        print("Well done! You won battleships! That was your {} time today".format(
            get_ordinal(self.games_won)
        ))
        print("You have played {} games so far, losing {}.".format(
            self.games_played,
            self.games_lost
        ))

        self.alert_finish()

    def alert_lost(self):
        print("Oh no! You lost! That was your {} time today. Better luck next time!".format(
            get_ordinal(self.games_lost)
        ))
        print("You have played {} games so far, winning {}.".format(
            self.games_played, self.games_won
        ))

        self.alert_finish()

    def alert_finish(self):
        print("This give you {}% win and you have a {:.0%} game win streak.".format(
            self.games_won / self.games_played,
            self.win_streak
        ))

    def finish_game(self, result):
        self.games_played += 1

        if (self.win_streak > 0) != result:
            self.win_streak = 0

        if result:
            self.win_streak += 1
            self.games_won += 1
        else:
            self.win_streak -= 1
            self.games_lost += 1

class BattleshipsGame:
    def __init__(self, turns, battleships):
        self.turn = 0
        self.turns_remaining = turns
        self.battleships_hit = 0
        self.battleships_remaining = battleships

    def next_turn(self):
        """Increments turn and checks if the game has ended"""

        self.turn += 1
        self.turns_remaining -= 1
        return self.turns_remaining == 0

    def hit_battleship(self):
        """Increments amount of battleships hit and checks if all have been hit"""

        self.battleships_hit += 1
        self.battleships_remaining -= 1
        return self.battleships_remaining == 0

def main():
    try:
        print(u"""Hello! Welcome to battleships, version 2.0.
Changelog:
- Complete rewrite
  - The game has multiple battleships now!
  - No longer any difficulty setting (because of said multiple battleships)
  - Now with \u221E% more classes!

Now, let's get started!
""")
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print("""Hello! Welcome to battleships, version 2.0.
Changelog:
- Complete rewrite
  - The game has multiple battleships now!
  - No longer any difficulty setting (because of said multiple battleships)
  - Now with infinity% more classes!

Now, let's get started!
""")
    stats = GameStatistics()

    confirmations_enabled = not bool_from_string(
        input("Would you like to disable confirmation messages? "),
        default=False
    )

    # Main game loop
    while True:
        s = "tall"
        while True:
            inp = input("How {} would you like the board? ".format(s))
            try:
                inp = int(inp)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please type in a number!")
                continue
            if inp < 4:
                print("Please type a value greater than 3!")
            elif inp > 25:
                confirmed = bool_from_string(
                    input("Do you really want a board dimension this big? "),
                    default=False
                )
                if not confirmed:
                    continue
            if s == "tall":
                s = "long"
                height = inp
            else:
                length = inp
                if confirmations_enabled:
                    a = bool_from_string(
                        input("Are you alright with a {} by {} board? ".format(height, length))
                    )
                    if a is None:
                        print("I'll take that as a \"Yes\"")
                    elif a:
                        print("OK! Let's continue!")
                    else:
                        s = "tall"
                        print("Try again then.")
                        continue
                break

        board = Board(height, length)
        max_battleships = int(0.5*sqrt(8*(height*length) + 1) - 0.5) - 2
#       Finds which triangle number the area of the board is inbetween
#       so you can't put more battleships than the board can take.
        while True:
            print("You can have a maximum of", max_battleships, "battleships",
                  "with your board size.")
            inp = input("How many battleships would you like? ")
            try:
                inp = int(inp)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please type a number!")
                continue
            if inp < 1:
                print("Please enter a value greater than 0!")
                continue
            elif inp > max_battleships:
                print("Please type a value less than", max_battleships)
                continue
            if confirmations_enabled:
                a = bool_from_string(input("Are you alright with " + str(inp) + " battleships? "))
                if a is None:
                    print('I\'ll take that as a "Yes"')
                elif a:
                    print("OK! Let's continue!")
                else:
                    print("Try again then.")
                    continue
            break
        battleships = inp
        while True:
            inp = input("How many turns would you like? ")
            try:
                inp = int(inp)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please type a number!")
                continue
            if inp < 1:
                print("Please enter a value greater than 0!")
                continue
            if confirmations_enabled:
                a = bool_from_string(input("Are you alright with " + str(inp) + " turns? "))
                if a is None:
                    print("I'll take that as a \"Yes\"")
                elif a:
                    print("OK! Let's continue!")
                else:
                    print("Try again then.")
                    continue
            break

        game = BattleshipsGame(inp, (battleships * (battleships + 1)) // 2)
#                             This equation shows which triangle number
#                             the battleship represents
        for i in range(battleships, 1, -1):
            board.add_battleship(size=i)
#           This makes the battleships increase in size, with their
#           lengths like (1, 2, 3) or (1, 2, 3, 4) etc.
        playing = True
        while playing:
            if game.turn == 0:
                print("Let's play Battleships!\n_turn 1, {} turn{}".format(
                    game.turns_remaining, "".join(
                        ["" if game.turns_remaining == 1 else "s"
                         for i in (1,)])), "remaining.")
            elif game.turns_remaining == 1:
                print("Last turn!")
            else:
                print("Turn {}, {} turns remaining.".format(
                    game.turn, game.turns_remaining))
            print(board)
            s = "Y"
            while True:
                inp = input(s + " coordinate: ")
                try:
                    inp = int(inp)
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please type a valid number!")
                    continue
                if s == "Y":
                    s = "X"
                    x = inp
                    continue
                y = inp
                if confirmations_enabled:
                    question = "Are you sure that you want to aim for {}, {}? ".format(x, y)
                    confirmed = bool_from_string(input(question), default=True)

                    if not confirmed:
                        print("Try again then.")
                        s = "Y"
                        continue
                break

            aim = board.attack_cell(x - 1, y - 1)

            if aim == AttackSuccess.hit:
                print("Congratualtions, you hit part of a battleship!")
                cont = game.hit_battleship()

            elif aim == AttackSuccess.miss:
                print("You didn't hit anything...")

            elif aim == AttackSuccess.out_of_bounds:
                print("That's not even in the ocean...")

            elif aim == AttackSuccess.already_hit:
                print("You already hit that one.")

            else:
                raise NotImplementedError

            if game.battleships_remaining != 0:
                cont = game.next_turn()
            if game.turns_remaining != 0 and \
               game.battleships_remaining != 0:
                continue
            else:
                board.reveal_board()
                print("\n" + str(board) + "\n_these were the battleships!")
            playing = False
            if cont:
                print("\n\n_restarting...\n\n")
                continuing = True
            else:
                continuing = False
        if continuing:
            continue
        print("Thanks for playing!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that `main` does not currently handle the changes to game flow made with regards to finishing the game.